# Помогите сделать перебор массива на JS

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = [5, 2, 5, 56, 2, 1, 2];
var b = [];
for (var c = 0; c < a.length; c++) {
  for (var q = 1; q < a.length; q++) {
    if (a[c] === a[q]) {
      //alert(a[q])
      b.push(a[q])
    }
  }
}
console.log(b)
```

Надо найти повторяющиеся значения и вывести их на консоль. Что я делаю не так????

Comment: А что не так???

Comment: кинь код на консоль трэш выдает...

Comment: можно (даже нужно) в вопросе включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку, чтоб не пришлось догадываться и кидать код в консоль.....

Comment: возьмите листок бумаги и карандаш. Выполните Ваш код шаг за шагом на бумаге, и все Ваши ошибки станут для Вас очевидны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var a = [5, 2, 5, 56, 2, 1, 2];
var b = {};
for(var c = 0; c < a.length; c++){
  b[a[c]] = b[a[c]]? (b[a[c]] + 1) : 1;
}
console.log(b);
for (var key in b) {
  if (b[key] > 1)
    console.log(key);
}
```